# Return-Path overwritten by Exim?

Tags: php, email, smtp

I have a VPS with cPanel and I'm using PHPMailer to send email through the local SMTP server which is run by exim, the problem is that I actually add:

```
$mail->AddCustomHeader('Return-Path: sender@domain.com');
```

But it's being overwritten with the default one, I know that I can do it with the `-f` 5th parameter in `mail()` but I want to do it using PHPMailer dynamically..

Appreciating any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHPMailer class has a `Sender` variable which sets the `-f` parameter (or constructs the appropriate `MAIL FROM:` command when using SMTP) as necessary. From the source code:

```
/**
 * Sets the Sender email (Return-Path) of the message.  If not empty,
 * will be sent via -f to sendmail or as 'MAIL FROM' in smtp mode.
 * @var string
 */
public $Sender            = '';
```

so you can presumably do something like:

```
$mail->Sender = 'sender@domain.com';
```

Outgoing mail servers tend to ignore Return-Path since they have the address from the SMTP `MAIL FROM:` line. The Return-Path header is inserted by the *recipient's* mail server for use in filters or other downstream processing.